# Trigger dbt models after snowflake snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Trigger dbt models after snowpipe
Hello,

I want to check the possibility of triggering dbt models after snowpipe load data into Snowflake database. I have a requirement where realtime xml data comes every time and I'll use snow pipe to ingest that data into snowflake. I want to know if there is a way to trigger dbt models that will load the variant field data to raw tables.

We are using airflow as orchestration to trigger the job periodically but today when 2500 files got accumulated in snowflake variant column table. Dbt job parsing the xml got memory issues during execution as processing 2500 xml files in on run caused this issue.

Is there a way we can batch the number of files we process or handle the snowflake memory issue

Thanks in advance !

Tried to execute them in smaller chunks with less than 500 files and it was working when we go beyond that sometimes its success and sometimes getting memory issues

Comment: Can you just use view materializations instead of relying on kicking off frequent DBT jobs? There are articles out there about how to achieve near real time DBT (ie, https://materialize.com/blog/real-time-dbt/), but my experience has been that either someone is given unnecessary requirements or the wrong architecture was chosen for the project. If you MUST kick off a job after Snowpipe, the only decent option I can think of is to set up a stream on top of your Snowpipe destination table, a task that runs every minute which scans for changed rows, then trigger DBT through an external function.

Comment: Is dbt parsing the xml and running out of memory, or is Snowflake parsing and running out of memory?